# How to parse within a certain section with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to parse a certain section of HTML code with beautifulSoup.

I can get a section of HTML code that I want to parse into  `section_I_want_to_parse`.

**MWE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.shopbot.com.au/pp-dji-mavic-mini-fly-more-bundle-price-564515.html'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
section_I_want_to_parse = soup.find("section", {"class": "sb-compare-prices", "id": "compare-prices"})
print(section_I_want_to_parse)  # This works - so far so good

# I want to use findAll within the section_I_want_to_parse
# price_list = section_I_want_to_parse.findAll("span", {"class": "sb-discounted-price"})
```

I want to `findAll("span", {"class": "sb-discounted-price"})` within `section_I_want_to_parse`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you paste a little sample HTML tag

Comment: I got it wrong, it's you:)

Comment: @dabingsou added a little more.

Comment: Perhaps `for span in section_I_want_to_parse.select('span.sb-discounted-price'): print(span.text)`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thank you! <3 - I was scratching my head for some time, read some sites but never would've thought it would be this simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions using simplifieddoc

```
import requests
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 

url = 'https://www.shopbot.com.au/pp-dji-mavic-mini-fly-more-bundle-price-564515.html'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(url, headers=header)

doc = SimplifiedDoc(page.text)
section_I_want_to_parse = doc.getElement("section", attr="id", value="compare-prices")
# print(section_I_want_to_parse)  # This works - so far so good
price_list = section_I_want_to_parse.getElements("span",attr="class",value="sb-discounted-price")

print ([price.text for price in price_list])
```

result：

```
['$799.00', '$799.00', '$799.00', '$799.00', '$799.00', '$799.00', '$799.00', '$799.00', '$958.80']
```